# Docker mounted volume - how to give cassandra permission to write to mounted volume folder

Tags: cassandra, docker, virtualbox

I am running cassandra in a docker container with a mounted volume(mac docker with VirtuelBox/boot2docker latest docker-machine). `docker run -v <src>:<dest>`. I am getting the beneath errors. I suspect that it has something to do with cassandra not having permission to write to data folder.


This use to work, but maybe it has been introduced with later version of VirtuelBox?[enter link description here](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/issues/24)

Cassandra errors:

```
ERROR 19:19:06 Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:1,1,main]
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /cassandra/cassdata_1/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmplink-la-5-big-Index.db -> /cassandra/cassdata_1/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmp-la-5-big-Index.db: Operation not permitted
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:93) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.makeTmpLinks(BigTableWriter.java:295) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.openFinalEarly(BigTableWriter.java:332) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.switchWriter(SSTableRewriter.java:298) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.doPrepare(SSTableRewriter.java:346) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:169) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.doPrepare(CompactionAwareWriter.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:169) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.finish(Transactional.java:179) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.finish(CompactionAwareWriter.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:196) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:74) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:236) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /cassandra/cassdata_1/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmplink-la-5-big-Index.db -> /cassandra/cassdata_1/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmp-la-5-big-Index.db: Operation not permitted
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:475) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createLink(Files.java:1039) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
ERROR 19:19:06 Exiting forcefully due to file system exception on startup, disk failure policy "stop"
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /cassandra/cassdata_1/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmplink-la-5-big-Index.db -> /cassandra/cassdata_1/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmp-la-5-big-Index.db: Operation not permitted
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:93) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.makeTmpLinks(BigTableWriter.java:295) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.openFinalEarly(BigTableWriter.java:332) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.switchWriter(SSTableRewriter.java:298) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.doPrepare(SSTableRewriter.java:346) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:169) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.doPrepare(CompactionAwareWriter.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:169) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.finish(Transactional.java:179) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.finish(CompactionAwareWriter.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:196) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:74) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:236) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /cassandra/cassdata_1/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmplink-la-5-big-Index.db -> /cassandra/cassdata_1/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmp-la-5-big-Index.db: Operation not permitted
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:475) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createLink(Files.java:1039) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Basically C* logs should be the first place that you need to look for potential problems. Please provide more details if you require any specific answer.

Comment: Are you getting errors?  You would look at errors first, and look in the logs, too.

Comment: All I see are warnings, Did anything actually break? Warnings are non-fatal conditions that you probably should fix.